# Getting right column with variable

Tags: excel, vba

I have simple table with some books and prices for borrowing them, I have one window which ask which book u want to borrow, and i wondering how to get right column for given variable

For example I want to get column G2 for book "Krzyżacy" in column K2.

[image]

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
Dim nazwa As String
nazwa = TextBox1.Value
Dim x As Range
   For Each x In Range("A2:A6")
   If StrComp(x.Value, nazwa) = 1 Then
    MsgBox nazwa
    Range("J2") = nazwa
    Range("K2") = x.Cells(G, CInt(nazwa))
    End If
    Next x

End Sub


Private Sub Label4_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Click()

End Sub
```

Comment: Did you try using `VLookup()`?

Answer (score 0):

Just to give you a head start, I have entered following formula in some cell and I got result 5:

```
=VLOOKUP("Krzy",A$2:G$5,7)
```

The "7" stands for column "G", which is the seventh column in range "A$x:G$y". The value "Krzy" is entirely correct, it should contain the full name.

In order to get this into code, this is the macro I've written:

```
Sub test()
  Range("H2").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(""Krzy"",A$2:G$5,7)"
End Sub
```

As you see, the double quotes need to be doubled, or VBA can't work with it.

Comment: ok, but when i want to use this in code i getting syntax error, dunno how it's works in code

Comment: @BartekSacha: I've added the macro code I've written, can you have a look?